# Jquery Load php

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm building a website where I load new data into the page by making and ajax request to a PHP page which pulls new data and then appends it to the document. There is a vote counter that counts the number of votes. The only problem here is I'm using another load function to increase the number of votes.

Programmatically, it is as follows

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'load.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
      var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
      if (json.status == 'newcontent') {
        $('.loadafter').before(json.content)
      }
    });
$.ajax({
    url: 'voteup.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
      var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
      if (json.status == 'success') {
        $("#votecount"+).load("home.php #votecount" + postid);
      }
```

the problem the second ajax request does not work for the new content that has been added by the previous Ajax request

Edit:The variable postid is used to target the post which is being voted up

Comment: Use `dataType: 'json'` and don't worry about parsing the response with `parseJSON`

Comment: There's not enough information here. What do you mean by *"the second ajax request does not work for the new content that has been added by the previous Ajax request"*? Where does `data` (the one used in the AJAX **request**) come from?

Comment: First ajax request refers to the ajax function with load as the url. The second ajax request refers to the function with vote up as the url.After new content is added to the Dom I want to allow people to vote up or down on the newly added content using Ajax to load the current number of voteups or down.

Comment: To clarify, what do you mean by *"does not work"*?

Comment: When I click on vote up on the newly added content it updates the database but it does not correctly load the html. For instance if post with id 10 has 10 votes and a user click to vote up the database shows 11 but the number 10 on the html varnishes.

Comment: Why don't you just have `voteup.php` return the new count as JSON? No need to make yet another AJAX request

Comment: Thank you Phil. I did that and its working great now.

Answer (score 0):

At a rough guess yout problem is `$("#votecount"+).load("home.php #votecount" + postid);`.

`$("#votecount"+)` isn't a valid selector. Try fixing that.

Also check what to you get when you call `"home.php #votecount" + postid` directly.

Comment: I believe the problem I'm having is I'm limiting the database query to only 6 rows and adding new content when the user hits the bottom of the page. Now when a user clicks vote up, the load function does not work as it should. When I look at my firebug console there is a get request to home but again it only gets the 6 initial post and leaves the new content out